# How to move element from an array into an variable in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, bit-manipulation

I have an Array as (filled with zeros and ones) -> ArrayWithContent[5] = {1,0,0,1,1};
Now I want this to be converted into an variable so I can read out the total value of this.

0001 0011 = 19

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    OneValue = ArrayWithContent[i]; 
    Variable = OneValue;
    Variable >>= 1;             // Send the zero or one to right.... continue to fill it up
}
```

Display Content of Variable I now want it to show the value 19.

I know I does this wrong, what is the correct way? Pointers and Addresses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Variable = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Variable = (Variable << 1) | ArrayWithContent[i];
}
```

Here:

- `(Variable << 1)` shifts the current value of `Variable` one bit to the left.
- `... | ArrayWithContent[i]` replaces the least-significant bit of the shifted value with `ArrayWithContent[i]`.
- Finally, `Variable = ...` assigns the result back to `Variable`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your loop, fixed:

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    OneValue = ArrayWithContent[i]; 
    Variable <<= 1;     // You want to shift to the left to keep the previous value.
    Variable |= OneValue; // You need to OR the value, else you'd erase the previous value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your data in big-endian format,
... either shift each value by the correct amount and OR everything together

```
value = 0;
for (i = 0; i < nelems; i++) {
    value |= (ArrayWithContent[i] << (nelems - i - 1));
}
```

... or keep shifting the current value by 1 bit and OR the next bit in

```
value = 0;
for (i = 0; i < nelems; i++) {
    value <<= 1;
    value |= a[i];
}
```